# Generating xml dynamically from a database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I cannot figure out the error which says

'This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.'

init.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = null;
$databaseName = "test";

$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, 
$password, $databaseName)

?>
```

viewWishList.php

```
<?php                                            
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
include ("config/init.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM members"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or 
die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

$_xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'                      
$_xml .="<wishList>"; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

$_xml .="<wishlist>"; 

$_xml .="<wishlistID>".$row['wishlistID']." 
</wishlistID>"; 
$_xml .="<bookName>".$row['bookName']." 
</bookName>"; 
$_xml .="<bookType>".$row['bookType']." 
</bookType>"; 

 $_xml .="</wishlist>"; 

 } 

 $_xml .="</wishList>"; 

$xmlobj=new SimpleXMLElement($_xml);                                                                                         
print $xmlobj->asXML();                                          
$xmlobj->asXML(wishlist.xml);

 ?>
```

Comment: dont see ;(semicolon) $_xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'

Comment: If you comment out `header ("Content-Type:text/xml");` what is displayed?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: connection in /opt/lampp/htdocs/a/viewWishList.php on line 27

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/a/viewWishList.php on line 27

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/a/viewWishList.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/a/viewWishList.php on line 27

Comment: Change the line to `$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or 
die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysqli_connect_error()); `

Comment: @NigelRen Still facing the same error.

Comment: How can you get the same error when the code doesn't reference the variable any more.  Also have you added the `;` as indicated in the first comment.

Comment: sorry got confused.. nothing is working
@NigelRen Notice: Undefined variable: connection(-tried even db same error-) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/a/viewWishList.php on line 26

Comment: Can you change the `include` to `require_once` to make sure the connection code is being loaded and make sure you use the code in the comment above for the connection.